# Nextcloud update hangs at Step 10

Tags: nextcloud

When almost finished, the nextcloud updater (to version 18.0.8.2, via Web-Interface) hung. After approx. 30 minutes I reloaded the page in the browser and then was denied access.

```
Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access /nextcloud on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

I checked the file permissions:

```
$ ls -la .htaccess 
-rw-r--r--. 1 myuser myuser 3032 Aug 26 17:38 .htaccess
```

I also tried:

```
$ tail cloud-data/updater.log 
2020-09-01T17:32:20+0200 kqivIsOYLg [info] endStep("9")
2020-09-01T17:32:21+0200 boz1aWdvr6 [info] request to updater
2020-09-01T17:32:21+0200 boz1aWdvr6 [info] currentStep()
2020-09-01T17:32:21+0200 boz1aWdvr6 [info] Step 9 is in state "end".
2020-09-01T17:32:21+0200 boz1aWdvr6 [info] POST request for step "10"
2020-09-01T17:32:21+0200 boz1aWdvr6 [info] startStep("10")
2020-09-01T17:32:21+0200 boz1aWdvr6 [info] moveNewVersionInPlace()
2020-09-01T17:32:21+0200 boz1aWdvr6 [info] storage location: /home/myuser/cloud-data//updater-oc4za7vxo38r/downloads/nextcloud/
2020-09-01T17:32:46+0200 boz1aWdvr6 [info] end of moveNewVersionInPlace()
2020-09-01T17:32:46+0200 boz1aWdvr6 [info] endStep("10")
$
```

It seems that the new files are already in place: at `/home/myuser/cloud-data/updater-oc4za7vxo38r/downloads/nextcloud/` only the updater remains and at `/home/myuser/html/nextcloud` are several folders with timestamp Sep 1 (that's when I ran the update).

Any tips how to debug further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started the update again via ssh / the NextCloud Console, with the command `php occ upgrade`. The update finished, and now I gained access via browser again.

Maybe the error was specific to the setup of my provider (uberspace). I was following [these instructions](https://lab.uberspace.de/guide_nextcloud.html#troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

There's [a script](https://docs.nextcloud.com//server/9/admin_manual/maintenance/update.html#set-updating-permissions-label) in the older Nextcloud documentation that sets the permissions such that the updater can do its work.

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # Sets permissions of the Nextcloud instance for updating
>
> ncpath='/var/www/nextcloud'
> htuser='www-data'
> htgroup='www-data'
>
> chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ncpath}
> ```

You can [set strict permissions afterwards](https://docs.nextcloud.com//server/9/admin_manual/installation/installation_wizard.html#strong-perms-label), but there's [a discussion going on](https://github.com/nextcloud/documentation/issues/1353) if that's desireable.